# User lacks privilege or Object not found error for saved query

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

With Java 8 not supporting JDBC I'm attempting to modify my program so it can still pull and modify data from a Microsoft Access database.

It keeps throwing an SQLException. Currently this is what my code looks like for opening a connection to the database and getting to the query:

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/Andrew/Dropbox/Public/Schoolwork/IRC/BBFBL/BBFBLMasterVersion3.accdb"); //name of ODBC driver
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DraftNightQuery");
```

And because I saw a similar question where the solution had to do with making sure the Query was typed correctly, this is the name of the table it's trying to access:

[image]

DraftNightQuery SQL:

```
SELECT Players.ID, Players.Last, Players.First, TotalStats.team, Players.DraftStatus, TotalStats.pos, Players.OwnerID, Owners.TeamName, Salaries!   [Salary] AS Salary, [TotalStats]![games_DH] AS DH, [TotalStats]![games_C] AS C, [TotalStats]![games_1B] AS 1B, [TotalStats]![games_2B] AS 2B, [TotalStats]![games_3B] AS 3B, [TotalStats]![games_SS] AS SS, [TotalStats]![games_LF]+[TotalStats]![games_CF]+[TotalStats]![games_RF] AS [OF], TotalStats.PG, TotalStats.GS, Players.PositionType
FROM Salaries INNER JOIN (Owners RIGHT JOIN (Players LEFT JOIN TotalStats ON Players.ID = TotalStats.ID) ON Owners.OwnerID = Players.OwnerID) ON Salaries.ID = Players.ID
WHERE (((Players.OwnerID) Is Null))
ORDER BY Players.Last, Players.First;
```

Comment: The issue isn't in the name of the query but in its content, that may  not be convertable by ucanaccess. That happens seldom, but it may be. You can see your db queries that ucanaccess can currently load by using the console(.bat or .sh) in the distribution. Also if you posted the query sql, I would be able to suggest how to convert it in a compatible manner. May you post it?

Comment: @jamadei If you're looking for the SQL of the DraftNightQuery, I've updated the original post to include that. Keep in mind that I didn't design this query, and I believe it was originally generated just by using the design view in Access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the query wasn't originally generated by using the design view in Access because the exclamation point (instead of a simple point) would have been used in particular cases. Anyway, the issue is in the use of the exclamation point which isn't supported yet by ucanaccess.
Replacing the ! with . should solve the issue (and it's compatible with ms access).

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have removed that error (although still working through other issues before the program works.) That's odd that it doesn't accept exclamation points.